# SUA C-Shell won't start

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, windows-server, sua

i install the Feature "subsystem for unix based application" on a Windows Server 2008 R2 x64 and the Utilities and SDK for Unix based Application, there was no errors while installation and logs. But i can't start the c-shell. Does anybody know how to debug it? I need the SUA for installing IBMs GPFS.

Thx

Comment: What happens when you try to run the shell?  Does it crash?  No window pops up at all?  Do you see anything in the Windows event log?

Comment: the window pops up, but it is blank and after 2 seconds it is closed. No Logs, no error ... nothing.

Comment: You can try starting the shell from `cmd` to look whether there is an error message or something before it closes.